# Sacar ruta de un fichero de un array de ficheros C#

Tags: c#, rutas, file

Tengo un array de ficheros, y tengo que obtener la cadena de la ruta de uno. No encuentro ningún método que lo haga. El código lo que hace es recorrerse dos directorios de ficheros, y luego buscar el primer fichero del directorio origen en el directorio destino. Este es mi código hasta ahora, las interrogaciones indican la duda que tengo:

```
 for (int i = 0;i<fileDirOrigenNames.Length;i++ )
 {
      System.IO.Stream[] arrayOrigen = new System.IO.Stream[i];

      for (int j = 0; j <= fileDirDestinoNames.Length; j++)
      {
            System.IO.Stream[] arrayDestino = new System.IO.Stream[i];
            if (arrayOrigen[i].Equals(arrayDestino[j]) == true)
            {
                //???????    mostrarResultadoComparacionPropiedades(arrayOrigen[i].ToString, arrayDestino[j].ToString);
            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde luego el código no hace lo que pretendes, aunque no sé si he entendido bien lo que intentas hacer.

Si lo que quieres es comprobar si los archivos de la ruta origen existen en la ruta destino aquí tienes un ejemplo de un método que lo hace.

Este código compara los archivos únicamente por nombre, si quieres comprobar el contenido ya habría que complicarlo algo más:

```
private static void CompararRutas(string origen, string destino)
{
    var sourceDir = new DirectoryInfo(origen);
    var targetDir = new DirectoryInfo(destino);
    var fileDirOrigenNames = sourceDir.GetFiles();
    var fileDirDestinoNames = targetDir.GetFiles();

    foreach (var sourceFile in fileDirOrigenNames)
    {
        var targetFile = fileDirDestinoNames.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == sourceFile.Name);
        Debug.WriteLine(
            $"El archivo {sourceFile.Name}{(targetFile == null ? " no" : "")} existe en la ruta destino ({destino})");
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, creo que me servirá! Pero tengo una duda con el operador =>, para que sirve?

Comment: Se trata de un operador que se utiliza para crear expresiones lambda las cuales sirven para definir funciones anónimas. En este caso define una función que recibe un objeto `FileInfo` y comprueba si su nombre coincide con el buscado. Más información sobre expresiones lambda: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como lo estás haciendo esta bien, el problema es que te faltan los paréntesis en el `ToString`:

```
for (int i = 0;i<fileDirOrigenNames.Length;i++ )
{
  System.IO.Stream[] arrayOrigen = new System.IO.Stream[i];

  for (int j = 0; j <= fileDirDestinoNames.Length; j++)
  {
        System.IO.Stream[] arrayDestino = new System.IO.Stream[i];
        if (arrayOrigen[i].Equals(arrayDestino[j]) == true)
        {
            mostrarResultadoComparacionPropiedades(arrayOrigen[i].ToString(), arrayDestino[j].ToString());
        }
   }
}
```